# How to add Azure VM's admin user to a specific unix group?

Tags: azure, packer

I'm creating an Azure VM image using Packer. The VM is just a Debian 10 installation with a couple of packages installed.

What I really need to do is to add VM admin user to a specific unix group (`docker`).

During the packer image provisioning I make changes to the `/etc/adduser.conf` to enable extra groups:

```
  "provisioners": [{
    "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo -E sh '{{ .Path }}'",
    "inline": [
      "apt-get update",
      "apt-get upgrade -y",
      "apt-get -y install docker.io",
      "echo 'ADD_EXTRA_GROUPS=1\nEXTRA_GROUPS=\"docker\"' >> /etc/adduser.conf",

      "/usr/sbin/waagent -force -deprovision+user && export HISTSIZE=0 && sync"
    ],
    "inline_shebang": "/bin/sh -x",
    "type": "shell"
  }]
```

But it only adds explicitly created users to the `docker` group but the the admin users created with the following command:

```
az vm create \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name myVM \
    --image myPackerImage \
    --admin-username azureuser \
    --generate-ssh-keys
```

Is there any way to add admin user to the group `docker` too?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you need, but I think you might need to look at `/etc/group` for that.

Comment: If you just want to add a user to the docker group, perhaps you want usermod -Ga docker -l <username>

Comment: @BruceBecker the problem is that the `<username>` is unknown because it is all performed on the image provisioning stage.

Comment: From what I understand `waagent` doesn't actually use `adduser` hence why changes to `/etc/adduser.conf` doesn't work.

Comment: @RichardSlater actually `waagent` uses `adduser`: https://github.com/Azure/WALinuxAgent/blob/3a3599b53121f5a2deb5761285657354610398fb/azurelinuxagent/common/osutil/default.py#L414

Comment: Actually that link shows it uses ‘useradd’, adduser is an abstraction over useradd, unfortunately its adduser that reads the adduser.conf.